# Using "selectbyexpression" command in standalone PyQGIS script

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

Is it possible to run "selectbyexpression" in a standalone PyQGIS script? Inside QGIS, I was using iface to add the map to the interface and now I don't know how to run it without using iface.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an expression to get the only the features you want.

```
request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression('my_field &gt; 20')
for feature in vector_layer.getFeatures(request):
```

see also
https://nyalldawson.net/2016/10/speeding-up-your-pyqgis-scripts/